# Determine the switching mode PS/adapter 12 or 24 V

Tags: identification, rectifier

How, by looking up components inside, to determine the switching mode PS/adapter is max 12 V or 24 V?

Comment: Without any point of reference, I'd say you'll need a crystal ball! Out of the many thousands of power supplies in the world, how can we know what you have?

Comment: Measure it? Check the nameplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How, by looking up components inside, to determine the switching mode PS/adapter is max 12 V or 24 V?

If you *cannot* switch-on the power supply to measure its output, but you *can* open it to view the components inside, as your question says, then there is a way to get a good (but imperfect) hint about whether it's a 12 V or 24 V output.

**Look at the voltage rating of the DC output capacitor(s).**

All switching power supplies will have one or more smoothing capacitors on each DC output. Higher voltage capacitors (a) tend to cost more money for the same capacitance value, and (b) tend to be larger than lower voltage capacitors with the same capacitance value. Therefore output capacitors *tend* to be rated *only moderately* above the normal DC output voltage.

For example:

- on a 5 V power supply, it's common to see output capacitors rated at 6.3 V or 10 V.
- on a 12 V power supply, it's common to see output capacitors rated at 16 V or 20 V.
- on a 24 V power supply, it's common to see output capacitors rated at 35 V or 50 V.

So in your case: If you see an output capacitor rated at 16 V or 20 V, then the power supply won't have a 24 V output voltage (unless it is a *very* poor quality, soon-to-fail power supply).

**Summary**

In your case with a choice between 12 V and 24 V: If you see a 35 V rated output capacitor, then that doesn't prove it's a 24 V output, and not a 12 V output, but it would tend to *hint* in that direction. But if you a 16 V or 20 V rated output capacitor, it's almost certain that it's a 12 V, not 24 V, output voltage on your power supply.